# Why isnt stylus input detected on my android screen

Tags: android, stylus-pen

I have a use case in my current android application that supports free hand annotations on pdf documents. I want to allow my users to create freehand annotations using either their finger or a stylus.

i have followed [this](https://large-screen-codelabs-main.zip) codelab, however when i try to draw with a stylus nothing happens, no lines are produced on the android device screen. only when i employ my finger are lines produced.

what am i missing?

is it possible to draw lines, write text with a stylus on an android device or not?

am i forced to employ a pen sdk to capture stylus pen strokes?